# Does laravel require a separate web server to run?

Tags: php, laravel

I am learning laravel for a school research project and am currently stuck at this. I have installed xampp and composer so far, I installed xampp to make use of the php.exe file that composer asks for, however, I realized that when I execute this command "php artisan serve" I am able to launch the new laravel project without having xampp running, does this mean that laravel does not require a separate server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does this mean that laravel does not require a separate server?

Not really, `php artisan serve` is only meant to be used for developing environment since it uses PHP's [built-in webserver](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php).
Taken from its documentation

> This web server was designed to aid application development. It may
>   also be useful for testing purposes or for application demonstrations
>   that are run in controlled environments. It is not intended to be a
>   full-featured web server. It should not be used on a public network.

In production you should use a better webserver such as [nginx](https://nginx.org/en/docs).